# WxPython, How to fill ListBox with class attributes

Tags: python, listbox, wxpython

I am building a wxpython project, I have a list of elements that are a class instances. Each of this elements has an attribute `title`. In a ListBox I want to display only the titles, and when the title selected, after we GetSelection from listbox, the instance should be returned and not just the title. Is this achievable ?

**Note:** Searching for the string is out of question because names(titles) may be recurring.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- Put your instances in a list
- Use `GetSelection` to retrieve the index of the item you selected from the listbox
- Get the corresponding instance from that index in the list